# How to do an automatic commit after successful merge?

Tags: git, command-line

I use this command:

```
git merge --commit  -m="Automatic commit" --progress my_branch/master
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Merge fail"
fi
```

The merge was successful and do not produce any conflict.
The git command output is:

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

Why it show: **stopped before committing as requested**? I want it commit if do not exist any conflict.

Any idea to make it automatic?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you aren't actually passing `--no-commit`?

Comment: (Just in case, to clarify: `--no-commit` causes *exactly* that behavior, and `--commit` is the exact *opposite* - and is also default.)

Comment: `--commit` does not solve problem (git v2.11.0)

Answer (score 2):

```
 stopped before committing as requested
```

That message should only happen when using the `--no-commit` option.
As illustrated in "[Mastering Git subtrees](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec#e790)", a [`git merge --squash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---squash) would also produce the same message.

So unless (perhaps) you might have a merge already in progress, you should not see that message.